# System of Linear Equations. Examples of 5 different solution sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking to find an example of each of the five types of solution sets in a 3x3 matrix with 3 unknowns.

- Unique Solution
- No Solution
- Line
- Plane
- All of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ for each situation?

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ in some basis.

Case 1: If $A$ is invertible $A\vec{x}=0\implies 0=A^{-1}\vec{x}$ the unique solution.

Case 2: $
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3& 2 \\
-2 & -1 & -2
\end{array} } \right]\vec{x}
 =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
-3 \\
1
\end{array} } \right]$ has no solution

Case 3:$A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} } \right]\vec{x}=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} } \right]$ the solutions are the $\vec{x}$ is the x-axis because it's the intersection of the three planes: $z=0$, $y=0$ and $z=y$.

Case 4:$A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} } \right]\vec{x}=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} } \right]$ the solutions are the $\vec{x}$ is the xy-plane because $z=0$ and $x,y$ can be anything
Case 5:$A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} } \right]\vec{x}=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} } \right]$ the solutions are every $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ because by definition, the zero matrix maps every vector to the zero vector

Answer (score 1):

Another post has provided specific answers to your question. My answer tries to explain why such a question might be asked in a textbook, and provide hints so you might solve the problem yourself.

I interpret your question to be, "For each condition in the bullet list below provide a 3x3 matrix A for which the solution of Ax = y satisfies that condition."

As a programmer you know that a good program must not be allowed to crash no matter what input is supplied.  I suspect the question you ask was created with this idea in mind.  As a result, do not fail to consider "silly" examples of 3 equations in 3 unknowns -- systems that nobody in his right mind would actually try to solve in a "real" application.

Case 2: Here is an 2x2 example of what I am calling "silly:"
 \begin{array}{cc}
x + y = & 5 \\
x + y = & 10 
\end{array} 
Such a system has no solution because how could two number add to 5 and also the **same** two numbers add to 10?

Case 5 (this is the answer is given above by user153582): A 3x3 system that will work for **every** value x, y, and z you substitute is
\begin{array}{cc}
x  = & x \\
y  = & y \\
z = & z
\end{array}
You put this into matrix form by putting the variables on the left.  This gives \begin{array}{cc}
x - x = & 0 \\
y - y = & 0 \\
z - z = & 0 
\end{array}
giving the strange looking system
\begin{array}{cc}
0 = & 0 \\
0 = & 0 \\
0 = & 0 
\end{array}
But there are supposed to be variables on the left side in order to change 3 equations in three unknowns to matrix form.  The trick is to write the left side as
\begin{array}{cc}
0x &+& 0y &+& 0z &=&0\\
0x &+& 0y &+& 0z  &=&0\\
0x &+& 0y &+& 0z &=&0,
\end{array}
which is the same as the matrix form given by user153582.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But did this answer my question though? I still don't know what bullets 3-5 are. Can you give me an example of each in solution set form?